# Finding the distribution of $f_{Y|X=x}$ and $f_{X|Y=y}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables.  $X$ has uniform distribution in $[-1,1]$, i.e, $F_{X} = 1/2$ in $[-1,1]$, and 0c.c. $Y = X^{2}$

What are the distribution of $f_{Y|X=x}$ and $f_{X|Y=y}$?

I found that the marginal o Y is: $f_{Y} = 1/2\sqrt{y}$. Am I right?

And then I, just stuck here: $f_{Y|X=x} = f_{x,y}/f_{x} = 2 f_{x,y}$

What can I do after this?

Any help?

Comment: If $Y=X^2$, **none of the PDFs** $f_{X,Y}$, $f_{Y\mid X=x}$ and $f_{X\mid Y=y}$ exist. But, conditionally on $X=x$, the distribution of $Y$ is a Dirac mass at $x^2$, and, conditionally on $Y=y$, $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{-\sqrt y,\sqrt y\}$. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Did Exactly! But I will need the $f(x,y)$ distribution, right? How can I find her?

Comment: Hmmm... Did you read my comment? Apparently not, so let me repeat: the PDF $f_{X,Y}$ does not exist.

Comment: Laura you may want to start with [Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: Laura I think what @Did hoped you would figure out is that while the probability distributions don't exist, the cumulative distributions $F_{X,Y}$, $F_{Y|X=x}$ and $F_{X|Y=y}$ exist.

Comment: @Mitjackson thank you very much! Now I get it. In some basic probability books this type of example are not found. Could you suggest a book, or any pdf that I could find examples like that?

Comment: @Laura Rosenthal? Durrett? P.S. Can you help with my [question on surface area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129816/surface-area-of-revolution-on-an-area-crossing-the-axis)?